# Name of an UWP app - Differences in Display Name and Package Display Name

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

What's the difference of "Display Name" in "Application" and "Package display name" in "Packaging", in Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: I dont know where package Display Name is used but Display Name is the name of the application that will be shown in search and in live tiles. The name of the uwp app will be the Display Name

Comment: But does the name of the application (the name that appears in the application list, store, etc.) have to match what I reserved right?

Comment: The application name as you described is the Display Name. The name that you reserve in Microsoft Store is another one and could be different.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: you can upvote the comments if it solves your problem.

Comment: @GeralexGR How is display name different from the name shown on Microsoft App Store? If my display name is X, then can I have Y on the app store for the same app? Please clarify.

Comment: @hellodear yes you can do that. You can name X your app, and so it will be displayed as X when it will be installed in a machine, but you can have your app named Y in the store, so a user will search it as Y.